# How to make a tesla coil play music?

Tags: tesla-coil, tuner

I'm building a Tesla Coil for a science project, and I thought it would be cool if I could make it play music. Could somebody tell me how? I'm new to this so please keep it as simple as possible.

Comment: What instrument were you thinking of having it play?

Comment: surely you just modulate its arcing to match the audio signal/tone you want?

Comment: http://www.stevehv.4hv.org/MusicalSSTCs.htm

Comment: simplest solution: google "musical tesla coil" and follow instructions

Comment: If you can not do the basic research on this, you probably should not be playing with the high voltage associated with Tesla coils... You need a staccato interupter.

Comment: I'd use a speaker and pretend it was coming from the tesla coil

Comment: Try to understand that the voltages you would be playing with are sufficient to kill you or cripple you for life should something go wrong. When everything is perfect it's nearly harmless, but putting yourself into cardiac arrest is pretty easy. Just don't lose perspective.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several flaws in your question, but here are the obvious ones:

- You do not mention your experience level with electronics, particularly high voltage projects
- You do not mention what type of Tesla coil you are building (SGTC, SSTC, DRSSTC, VTTC, QCWDRSSTC, etc). Some of them you cannot modulate.
  From reading your question, you strike me as not being very experienced, which makes building an audio-modulated Tesla coil extremely difficult (if not impossible). There is a lot of math, physics, and electronics involved in audio TCs, and should not be attempted as a first coil.

Just stick with a SGTC for now. They're the easiest to build and there's less of a chance of exploding electronics. Forget about making it audio modulated for now.